# Cannot create new project in netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: java, netbeans, ubuntu-14.04

i install netbeans 8.0.2 on ubuntu 14.04. i can open my older project. The problem happens when i create new project.

here is the error :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openide.WizardDescriptor$WizardPanel$AccessibleWizardPanel
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
            at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:222)
        Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openide.WizardDescriptor$WizardPanel$AccessibleWizardPanel starting from ModuleCL@5d1b0d65[org.openide.dialogs] with possible defining loaders [ModuleCL@5d1b0d65[org.openide.dialogs]] and declared parents [org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@48454bc7, ModuleCL@5eebd82d[org.openide.awt], ModuleCL@4dbda30a[org.netbeans.api.progress]]
            at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:224)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openide/WizardDescriptor$WizardPanel$AccessibleWizardPanel
            at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.updateStateOpen(WizardDescriptor.java:911)
            at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.updateState(WizardDescriptor.java:822)
            at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.updateState(TemplateWizard.java:754)
            at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.NewProjectWizard.updateState(NewProjectWizard.java:71)
            at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard$2.run(TemplateWizard.java:497)
            at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard$2.run(TemplateWizard.java:494)
            at org.openide.util.Mutex$1AWTWorker.run(Mutex.java:1394)
            at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:302)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
            at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
        [catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

what is wrong? i have update my netbeans.

Comment: There is always an issue with an update of NetBeans IDE! I mean to say go through their website, that'd help.

Comment: Do you have this issue with NB 8.1 too?

Comment: yes, i do. still doesnt work.